# InfluxDB: Starting cumulative_sum() from zero / aggregate grouping required for cumulative_sum and non_negative_difference

Tags: influxdb

Using InfluxDB, I'm trying produce an output that shows cumulative rainfall for a time period, that starts from zero.

The rainfall sensor outputs a cumulative rainfall amount, but resets to zero on power-failure, restart etc.

My first query component uses `non_negative_difference()` to show the increments.

```
select 
    non_negative_difference(rain) as nnd 
FROM 
    weather  
WHERE 
    $time_query
```

.... yields an increment per raw data point, for example:

```
2018-06-01T14:21:00.926Z 0
2018-06-01T14:22:02.959Z 0.30000000000000426
2018-06-01T14:23:04.992Z 0.3999999999999986
2018-06-01T14:24:07.024Z 0.10000000000000142
2018-06-01T14:25:09.059Z 0.19999999999999574
2018-06-01T14:26:11.094Z 0
2018-06-01T14:27:13.127Z 0.10000000000000142
2018-06-01T14:28:15.158Z 0.20000000000000284
2018-06-01T14:29:20.027Z 0.09999999999999432
2018-06-01T14:30:22.476Z 0.10000000000000142
2018-06-01T14:30:53.918Z 0.6000000000000014
2018-06-01T14:31:55.968Z 0.5
2018-06-01T14:32:58.007Z 0.5
2018-06-01T14:34:00.046Z 0.20000000000000284
2018-06-01T14:35:02.075Z 0.3999999999999986
2018-06-01T14:36:04.102Z 0.3999999999999986
2018-06-01T14:37:06.136Z 0.20000000000000284
2018-06-01T14:38:08.201Z 0
```

**So far so good.**

I'm now trying to stitch these readings back to cumulative total, starting from zero for the intended period.

I can use `cumulative_sum()` for this, for example:

```
SELECT 
    cumulative_sum(nnd) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        non_negative_difference(rain) as nnd 
     FROM 
        weather
     WHERE 
        $time_query )
```

which yields:

```
2018-06-01T14:21:00.926Z 0
2018-06-01T14:22:02.959Z 0.30000000000000426
2018-06-01T14:23:04.992Z 0.7000000000000028
2018-06-01T14:24:07.024Z 0.8000000000000043
2018-06-01T14:25:09.059Z 1
2018-06-01T14:26:11.094Z 1
2018-06-01T14:27:13.127Z 1.1000000000000014
2018-06-01T14:28:15.158Z 1.3000000000000043
2018-06-01T14:29:20.027Z 1.3999999999999986
2018-06-01T14:30:22.476Z 1.5
2018-06-01T14:30:53.918Z 2.1000000000000014
2018-06-01T14:31:55.968Z 2.6000000000000014
2018-06-01T14:32:58.007Z 3.1000000000000014
2018-06-01T14:34:00.046Z 3.3000000000000043
2018-06-01T14:35:02.075Z 3.700000000000003
2018-06-01T14:36:04.102Z 4.100000000000001
2018-06-01T14:37:06.136Z 4.300000000000004
2018-06-01T14:38:08.201Z 4.300000000000004
```

**Looking good!**

Now I'd like to group it up into more distinct time buckets, for nice graphing.

Let's try....

```
SELECT 
    cumulative_sum(max(nnd))
FROM (SELECT 
          non_negative_difference(rain) as nnd 
      FROM 
          weather
      WHERE
          $time_query)
GROUP BY
    time(5m)
```

and I get an error: `ERR: aggregate function required inside the call to non_negative_difference`

But I cannot find a reasonable way of adding aggregates and groupings to `non_negative_difference()` that do not affect the accuracy of the differencing function itself.

The only thing I've been able to do is a dummy aggregate SUM() over time groups that are smaller than the sensor period. But this isn't robust enough for my liking - (and i'm still not sure it is 100% correct)

Is it correct that I must have both queries as aggregate queries?

Comment: Please clarify how grouping and aggregates affect accuracy of non_negative_difference in your case. If `rain` is an increasing counter (except resets) non_negative_difference(last(rain)) should produce reasonable data.

Comment: if a counter reset occurs within a GROUP BY period, then last() will not show the effects leading up to the reset. (unless, like my SUM(), the GROUP BY period is less than the raw data period).  But my question is more to do with why I need to have nested aggregates, when an aggregate of the outer would be sufficient

Comment: Required aggregate smells like influxql bug. Influxdata doc states that aggregate inside non_negative_difference is needed in what they call "advanced syntax" for this function when group by time is used in select. I believe the last comment in this issue (https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/9844) explains your case too.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this very thing for my weather station. Instead of having the weather station calculate the cumulative value I wanted Grafana to do it. The solution that worked for me is the advanced syntax Yuri Lachin mentions in his comments.

With InfluxDB you can use `CUMULATIVE_SUM()`, but the basic syntax doesn't allow you to group by time (only by tag). The "advanced syntax", however, allows you to to have a time series by nesting an aggregate function like `MEAN()` or `SUM()`.

Here's the function I am using in Grafana to get a cumulative rainfall total for a selected time period:
`SELECT CUMULATIVE_SUM(MEAN("rainfall")) FROM "weather" WHERE $timeFilter  GROUP BY time(1h) fill(0)`.

The `GROUP BY` is, of course, flexible. I was interested in hourly rainfall so I grouped by 1h. You can group by the time period you find most interesting.

Using this query the rainfall will start from zero for period you select in Grafana. In the Seattle area we had measurable rain (I know, shocker) on 8/6/2020 and 8/8/2020. If I set my date range to include both dates the graph shows just under .2mm total rainfall:
[image: Graph showing 3 day period with rainfall]

If I switch my graph to 8/8 and 8/9 the total is just under 1mm:
[image: Graph showing 1 day period with rainfall]

Note: I was also interested in seeing the individual bucket tips so included those as bars on the second Y-axis.

[image: Grafana query examples for rainfall]

For more detail see: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#advanced-syntax-7